# Reacting to multiple iBeacons

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I have been playing around with iBeacons for a few weeks now and was woundering if it was possible to monitor two beacons from the same view controller.

For example so far I have made an app with three sperate views that each react to a seperate beacon changing content dependent on range and triggering dynamic content like music and video. All these view are the same layout so I was woundering if I could change it so I had one view controller that changed the content dependent on what beacon I am near rather than having to change the view.

This would make more sense as you can only monitor one which means when the segue triggers and the new beacon is being monitored if you move back towards the first beacon it doesn't chnage back to that view when you enter the first beacons proximity.

I'm sure there is a way to do this as beacons are being used in apple store in america to trigger promotion, etc and they changhe dependednt on the closest beacon with no problem.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ExhibitsViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
CLBeacon *beacon;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager

@end
```

This is the code in my header file that is defining the beacon, beaconRegion and locationManager.

```
#import "MultipleBeaconsViewController.h"

@interface MultipleBeaconsViewController ()  
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *rangeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *uuidLabel;
@end

@implementation MultipleBeaconsViewController

NSUUID *iBeacon1uuid;
NSUUID *iBeacon2uuid;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
[self initRegion];

[self locationManager:self.locationManager didStartMonitoringForRegion:self.iBeacon1Region];
[self locationManager:self.locationManager didStartMonitoringForRegion:self.iBeacon2Region];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)initRegion {

iBeacon1uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555"];
_iBeacon1Region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:iBeacon1uuid identifier:@"com.private.Gallery"];
_iBeacon1Region.notifyOnEntry = YES;
_iBeacon1Region.notifyOnExit = YES;

// launch app when display is turned on and inside region
_iBeacon1Region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;

if ([CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]])
{
    [_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:_iBeacon1Region];
    [_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:_iBeacon1Region];
}

iBeacon2uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"55555555-4444-3333-2222-111111111111"];
_iBeacon2Region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:iBeacon2uuid identifier:@"com.private.Gallery"];
_iBeacon2Region.notifyOnEntry = YES;
_iBeacon2Region.notifyOnExit = YES;

// launch app when display is turned on and inside region
_iBeacon2Region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;

if ([CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]])
{
    [_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:_iBeacon2Region];
    [_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:_iBeacon2Region];
}
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {

if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]])
{

    CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = (CLBeaconRegion *)region;

    if ([beaconRegion.proximityUUID isEqual: iBeacon1uuid])
    {
        _titleLabel.text = @"Beacon 1 proximity entered";

    }
    else if ([beaconRegion.proximityUUID isEqual: iBeacon2uuid])
    {
        _titleLabel.text = @"Beacon 2 proximity entered";
    }

}

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{

if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]) {

    CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = (CLBeaconRegion *)region;


    if ([beaconRegion.proximityUUID isEqual: iBeacon1uuid])
    {

        _titleLabel.text = @"Beacon 1 proximity exited";
    }
    else if ([beaconRegion.proximityUUID isEqual: iBeacon2uuid])
    {

        _titleLabel.text = @"Beacon 2 proximity exited";
    }

}
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
{

if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]) {

    for (CLBeacon *beacon in beacons)
    {

        NSString *beaconID = [beacons objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%@",beaconID);

        if ([region.proximityUUID isEqual:iBeacon1uuid])
        {

            if (beacon.accuracy >=0.000001 && beacon.accuracy <=0.500000)
            {
            _titleLabel.text = @"Beacon 1";
            _rangeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",beacon.accuracy];
            _uuidLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", beacon.proximityUUID];
            }
        }
        else if ([region.proximityUUID isEqual:iBeacon2uuid])
        {
            if (beacon.accuracy >=0.000001 && beacon.accuracy <=0.500000) {
                _titleLabel.text = @"Beacon 2";
                _rangeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",beacon.accuracy];
                _uuidLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", beacon.proximityUUID];
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

This is my code in the implementation file that is ranging the beacon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. To do that you don't have to keep property self.beaconRegion you just create as many as you like and start monitor and start ranging for it, for example this is how I do that:

//Reion 1

```
CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid major:major minor:minor identifier:identifier];
region.notifyOnEntry = YES;
region.notifyOnExit = YES;
// launch app when display is turned on and inside region
region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;

if ([CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]])
{
    [_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
    [_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];
}
```

//Region 2

```
   CLBeaconRegion *region2 = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid2 major:major2 minor:minor2 identifier:identifier2];
    region2.notifyOnEntry = YES;
    region2.notifyOnExit = YES;
    // launch app when display is turned on and inside region
    region2.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;

    if ([CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]])
    {
        [_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region2];
        [_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region2];
    }
```

// and so on

After that in every self.locationManager delegate method make sure which beacon you have, for example:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {

    if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]) {
        CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = (CLBeaconRegion *)region;

        // Find out which beacon you have,
        // I check just UUID but maybe your beacons have the same uuid but major, minor are difference so you need to check minor/major as well
        if ([beaconRegion.proximityUUID isEqual:UUIDFIRST]) {

            //Do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to see which beacon are nearest you use:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
```

enumerate beacons array:

```
if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]) {

        for (CLBeacon *beacon in beacons) { // 1
            // do the checking which beacon you have
            if ([beaconRegion.proximityUUID isEqual:UUIDFIRST]) { // 2

            }

                 // check beacon.accuracy property this should gives you distance in meters meters
                 //beacon.accuracy // 3
            }
        }
    }
```

// Extended

If you are in range two (or more) beacons the beacons are passed to you in beacons array. By calling [beacons lastObject] you get just one beacon. What you have to do is enumerate (go throughout all of the objects in array) see no 1 in my code above (I edited it a bit) and see what beacon you have (2) after that you compare the distance (3) and the one with less value is the nearest one.

Comment: Hi I tried using this to solved the issue, I am now able to see the second beacon but the app only ever ranges the second beacon even when right next to the first beacon. The only differents in my code is that I'm still using the "iBeacon = [beacons lastObject];. Would you be able to explain to me what you meant when you wrote "enumerate beacons array"

Comment: Hi sorry to bother you again still haveing a problem with the app only finding the second beacon, I have checked the items in the array using NSLog and found that it was only finding one beacon, if I then commented out the 2nd region it would find the first beacon but this was the only way I could get it to find the first beacon. I have edited my original post to include the new code, incase I did something wrong

Comment: Replace your log (NSLog(@"%@",beaconID);) in didRangeBeacons: methods to NSLog(@"UUID: %@", beacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString); and you should see two beacons

Comment: I have done that an I'm still only see the one beacons, once I comment out the "startMonitoring" & "startRanging" the first beacon can be seen.

Comment: Change the identifier to be different for range 1 and different for range 2.

Comment: Sorry is me being stupid, very new to iBeacons but not sure what you mean but the identifier, do you mean the pointer name I gave the region with beacons UUID?

Comment: [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:iBeacon1uuid identifier:@"com.private.Amsys-Gallery1"];   [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:iBeacon1uuid identifier:@"com.private.Amsys-Gallery2"];

Comment: I was running some tests on this app, I added a label that udated with the beacons UUID so i could tell which one was registering and I noticed that even through I was stood next to the beacon a different UUID was showing as the nearest beacon

Comment: Add two label to your app and display beacon.accuracy for both. You will see how the distance is changing based on your iPhone location and beacon transmitters.

Comment: I have done that and even though a different beacon is closer the UUID and range is still showing for the other beacon

Comment: It means that the logic you applied to display the label is wrong. If you can see the distance and it's right it means that the app pick up the beacons signal right. I cannot help if I cannot see the code. This is different issue so maybe create another post.

Comment: My code is the same as above I chamged the identifies and it started working but takes a while to react to changes

Comment: I am storing my beacon's UUID as a NSString or as a object in array and comparing it with beacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString isEqualTo method to my array's object and even string, both values show exactly same as each other in NSLogs yet isEqualTo always returns False (1)
Anyone has any idea why ?

Comment: ranging is only for one becaonregion.

Answer (score 3):

A UUID can be reused on many iBeacons. Each beacon has a major and a minor number to differentiate each one.

So a company would buy a single UUID, but (taking a store),

All majors = 1 are on the first floor:

- minor 1 = to womens clothes
- minor 2 = mens clothes

Major 2 = second floor:

- minor 1 = kids clothes
- minor 2 = footwear

... and so on. As the app walks around the store the beacons can tell it where they are and offer ad's / videos depending on the data.

You check for these values inside your `didRangeBeacons` callback. I also believe an app can monitor up to 20 regions at once, so the `region` attribute inside that callback would contain the different UUID

Comment: I undated my code above, As you can see the UUID's are completely different for the beacons, Unfortuantely my boss it the one who configured the beacons and refuses to change the UUID's so they are very different so I need to monitor two with completely diffrent UUIDs

Comment: @DavidHare ok, well on a side note your boss should change them. If your going to use a technology you should conform to the standard. Aside from that your for loop is wrong. `for (CLBeacon *beacon in beacons)` here you have a for each loop where `beacon` is going to be a pointer to each object in turn, yet on the first line you always pull out the first beacon in the array. What you are doing is running the same code multiple times on the same object, either use a for loop with an index or update your code to use `beacon` instead of pulling it out of the array

Comment: @DavidHare - using different region UUIDs works as long as you only need to simultaneously model a very small number, but it does not scale as iOS places a low limit on the number which can be monitored at once.  So your organization will need to change its assignment practices before doing a large-scale rollout.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I am aware of this, the beacons are only being used for the app for an afternoon, that is why my boss doesn't wish to change the UUID's as they will be going back to their perminate positions after.

Answer (score 0):

The identifier provided in

```
[[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:iBeacon1uuid identifier:@"com.private.Gallery"];
```

has to be different for each beacon you are monitoring.

In your case, they are both @"com.private.Gallery"